# Received coins in offline Armory wallet that had not yet been synced

Tags: synchronization, armory

I'm new to the Bitcoin world and I have an issue. I created a wallet in Armory but did not realize that it was offline and the db had not been spawned.

I have no way of downloading the full armory ledger at this point due to space issue.

I created a wallet and got a delivery address and initiated a transaction of 0.1 btc to it that I cannot cancel.

Is the delivery address valid even though armory was never connected to the internet?

Can I access the funds at a later time with the private key that was generated by armory?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Is the delivery address valid even though armory was never connected to the internet ?

Yes. There is no need for a wallet to be online to receive Bitcoin.

> can i access the funds at a later time with the private key that was generated by armory ?

Yes. Once Armory and Core are fully synced, you can access the funds. Alternatively you can export your private keys and import/sweep them into another wallet and access your funds from there.